# Upgrading Directus 7 by using git causes error when using - git pull origin

Tags: directus

According to the Directus documenentation, https://docs.directus.io/guides/upgrading.html
the correct procedure to upgrade a current version 7 to newer version (7.x) is by pulling the new version from git:

```
git pull origin
```

However, this results in an error stating that the local changes e.g. in the files for migrations located in: migrations/db/schemas/
and some more locations will be overwritten thus the operation will not be performed (ending with an error).

Are the instructions on the linked page incorrect or am I doing something wrong here?

Any help is appreciated

/Chris

Comment: Have you got a dump of the error message? Sounds like you have uncommitted changes in local repository.

Comment: That was the case actually (didn't think about that when not actively contributing to the collective code base of the application). After making a commit the problem was solved, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that you've manually modified files within Directus, therefore your local Git is expecting the changes to be committed before updating, you may need to update by force, but any changes you've made will be overwritten.

Your config.php and uploads should remain untouched.